# Is negative square root defined for a positive semidefinte matrix?

Tags: positive-semidefinite

If I have a positive semidefinite matrix $A$, is an operation like $A^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ defined? I know it is defined for positive definite matrices but for the positive semidefinite case, do the zero eigenvalues cause trouble or do we just consider them to be $0$?

Comment: What do you want $A^{-1/2}$ to _mean_? What defining property do you want it to fulfill? Once you have an answer to that, I think you can answer your own question. Especially if you consider that the zero matrix is a positive semi-definite matrix.

Answer (score 1):

For any real symmetric matrix $A$ and any real function $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ we can define $f(A)$ as follows. Let $A=Q^TDQ$ be an orthogonal diagonalization of $A$ (which exists by the spectral theorem, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices)), so that $D$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$ appearing on the diagonal. Then define
$$
f(A):=Q^Tf(D)Q,
$$
where $f(D)$ means we form a diagonal matrix by applying $f$ to each diagonal entry of $D$.

Now you are interested in a function from $\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R$, but we can apply the same approach in this case under the additional hypothesis that all eigenvalues are strictly greater than zero - i.e., a positive *definite* matrix, rather than positive *semi*definite as you wrote.

Since you are insisting on considering the positive *semi*definite case, you will need to make some nonstandard definitions. The one that seems least contrived to me is to extend the matrix entries to the extended reals $\{-\infty\}\cup\mathbb R\cup \{\infty\}$, and consider the function $f\colon \mathbb [0,\infty)\to (0,\infty]$ defined by
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}x^{-1/2},&x>0\\ \infty,&x=0.
\end{cases}
$$